# Send Email Notifications from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I have created a Kibana Dashboard which reports the user behaviour. Now based on the dashboard and graphs I want to send a email notification to my team by alerting which user behaviour is not good and which one is performing good.

I know that we can set email alerts on ES log monitoring. Is there any option from kibana dashboard where I can send custom notifications to my team by mentioning the user behaviour.

Comment: if you have an elastic license you can use their alerting product ( aka watchers ). See here https://www.elastic.co/products/stack/alerting

Comment: @PierreMallet. As I mentioned, from ES its possible to send alerts. But I want from Kibana and I hope you got my requirement.

Comment: Im not sure to see your point. Kibana is for visualization and the elastic stack have a specific product for alerting. I don't think there is a magic button in Kibana to handle alerting ( or they would not have created a specific product ). But i would glad to be wrong